# Which Roman writer wrote this passage?

Tags: ancient-rome

I'm operating off of fuzzy memory here and I’m unable to find the source of this passage. Some time ago, I read a passage from some ancient Roman writer that went something like this:

> “**He came and he brought with him (paper) rolls with written historical events laid down in a manner so you could see them all together and compare the events**”

The receiver (of the paper rolls) might be a Roman emperor, or someone related to emperor’s teaching: maybe Hadrian, Marcus Aurelius, or similar emperors.

- I remember a fuzzy concept of  “paper rolls”, “table format” or “events in different columns”.
- I remember the text was a letter, or similar. There were only 2 people involved.
- I remember it was casual talk, like you talk to a friend that brought/sent something interesting at home.

That’s it. I cannot recall more info than that. I’ve checked Memoirs of Hadrian (by Yourcenar), and Marcus Aurelius letters too. The passage is certainly not there. Maybe in similar texts.

Any clues on how to find this passage and the author are welcome.

Comment: This sentence could not be written by a Roman writer since paper was invented in China, and was not produced or used in the Roman empire.
So the sentence comes either from a modern author, or is a bad translation of some Roman source. One of the well-known popular authors of historical novels (Robert Graves) consciously modernizes his terminology, and I remember seeing "paper", and other modern words
(like "general", "admiral") in his novels.

Comment: This was a "fuzzy memory" of a passage "that went something like this".  I don't think that questioning the precise wording is likely to be useful -- we need to focus on the gist.

Comment: You are correct Alex, I remember the "rolls" part, but not the paper. I added it though since rolls alone is unclear.

Comment: Could show some context, please? In and of itself, why would such a general passage be attributed to a single writer and how could the attribution matter?

Comment: Any further clues yet? Sounds like a novice describing 'first insights into historiography'—IE quite a novelty for the writer of the passage? Was it a Roman author (or Greek), one _about_ such people (like an 'old Roman', republic, 'learning the Greek way'?) From these I get the _feeling_ of either 'very old' or not about imperial Romans self-description?

Comment: Further clues: the two people talking could be tutor-student. Also, my guess is for very late republican or early imperial Rome, but again, my memory is fuzzy about this.

Comment: The citation is important as it mentions lists of historical events in table or similar (graphical) layout, a type of work different from narrative work. A type of work that could be an evolved **annales tradition** type (list of events, year by year).

Comment: French _annales?_ I see your aim (the timeline thingy), but I doubt a bit that it really was _tabular_ (at least as xcel-like I envision that now). My hunches point toward a convenient _syn-opsis_ for those many _details_ — when having the scrolls side-by-side (like on a Kremlin-table ;). Somehow that does ring a distant bell, but all research ideas so far rested on too generic words in Latin (can you exclude Greek?) and probably 1 or 2 misplaced terms…

Comment: Not the French Annales School, but Roman Annalist tradition. See https://www.britannica.com/topic/annalist Yes, I think it is a Latin author. What do you mean by a Kremlin Table?

Comment: The e threw me off for use in this description; but have you checked 'The Fragments' of those Roman annalists? Your scenario sounds like a description of usage of their output. But generally, your 'table' ('graphical') sounds to me like ~Eusebius/chronicle or later (btw [the big Kremlin table already with own WP entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vladimir_Putin%27s_meeting_table)), although sth like Parian Marble Chronicle might also fit, if it weren't for the _different_ 'scrolls' compared. — Please lift anything useul from comments into Q and then flag the comments obsolete as you see fit.